# Chrome how to show computed with styles at the same time

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to have it in chrome dev tools like in Firefox? Two columns on the right side, one showing styles, other one computed styles. [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwBqc.png)

Comment: The only way is to make devtools narrow i.e. dock it vertically.

Comment: @wOxxOm That's not exactly what I mean, I don't want it narrower, just side by side those two tabs.

Comment: There's no other way. In the future the panels will be configurable but the development of this feature hasn't even started.

Comment: The panels used to be side by side..!  Oh happy days...

Comment: I switched to Firefox Developer Edition for dev completely and must say, it's much better than Chrome :) Dev tools are just next level with exception of network tab, that one is better in Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Toggle this icon for computed sidepanel

[image: Toggle this icon for computed sidepanel]

Comment: Exactly what OP asked for. This should be marked as _answer_ @leachim

Answer (score 2):

Chrome used to display the "Styles" and "Computed" Tabs at the same time side by side as you mentioned. But a recent update might have changed that. Now you can only view one tab at a time.

Comment: Oh no ! I always had them both open! Will file a chrome bug report / feature request when I have time. Now that I'm swapping tabs constantly I barely have time to do anything else!!